# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined in highcharts

Tags: extjs4, highcharts

I'm facing this error when I'm trying to add highchart in extjs panel:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined  in highchart.js
```

testing.js

```js
var chartObject = new Chart.ux.HighChart({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]

});
```

`error on highchart.js:275`

https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highcharts_ExtJs_4/blob/master/Chart/ux/HighChart.js

Answer (score 0):

Define your chart configuration in chartConfig:

```js
chartConfig : {
    chart : {
        // ...
    },
    title : {
      text : '....',
      x : -20 //center
    },
    subtitle : {
      text : '....',
      x : -20
      },
      xAxis : [{

      //... and so on
```

Look at this [example](https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highcharts_ExtJs_4/blob/master/standalone.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can download highchart.zip file in this url http://www.highcharts.com/download

In this zip file no errors in highcharts.js.

EDIT:
You can also use files from http://code.highcharts.com